# Large and Sparse Matrix Multiplcation

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, matrix-multiplication, sparse-matrix

I have a very large and sparse matrix of size 180GB(text , 30k * 3M) containing only the entries and no additional data. I have to do matrix multiplication , inversion and some similar linear algebra operations over it. I tried octave and simple single-threaded C code for the multiplication but my system RAM of 40GB gets used up very fast and then I can find the program starts thrashing. Is there any other options available to me. I am not familiar with MathLab or any other matrix operational library that can help me in doing so.

When I run a simple matrix multiplication of two matrices with 10 rows and 3 M cols, and its transpose, it gives the following error :

```
    memory exhausted or requested size too large for range of Octave's index type
```

I am not sure whether the same would work on Matlab or not. For sparse matrix representation and matrix multiplication, is there another library or code.

Comment: Are you saying that the full matrix data is 180GB, or do you mean that the sparse representation itself is 180GB?  What are the matrix dimensions, and how many non-zero elements do you have?

Comment: You need the *inverse* of such a matrix? Are you sure you don't need the *product* `A*x`? (which can be calculated a *lot* faster and a *lot* more accurate than the explicit inverse...)

Comment: I would just like to chime in and say that that is a HUGE matrix. Care to share what all of that data is for? I think you are going to need to look in to algorithms for very large datasets (VLD), or datasets that are too large to store in memory all at once. I know there are algorithms for doing operations on these, but they are a little outside of my area. I would be curious to see what you find.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis : At present I need just matrix transpose(can be done via awk or other simpler code) and matrix multiplication on the variants of that matrix like A * A' , etc.

Comment: @Engineero : The data is distributional statistics representation of very large combined corpuses in English for nlp purpose. Can you give me some pointers to find my solutions in VLD, you mentioned earlier

Comment: @paddy : The matrix is tab separated values in matrix representation. The matrix dimension is 30k * 3 million. It is very sparse ( I haven't calculated the exact sparsness but can safely say that it is greater than 99.99% sparse).

Comment: Have you tried using `sparse` in Matlab?

Comment: how do you read this matrix into mem, anyhow?

Comment: @Shai : Isn't  `sparse` meant for generating sparse matrix. Btw, at present I am not using Matlab but Octave instead. The matrix is read from tab separated values from text file like `load matrix.txt`. I then try to perform operations on it.

Comment: if I get it right, you are able to load the entire 180GB matrix into an octave variable, then you run into memory troubles as soon as you try to fiddle with the huge variable? Can you cast/convert the huge variable into `sparse`, e.g., `m=readFromFile( hugeFileName.txt );m=sparse(m);`?

Comment: @Shai Nope, I am trying with only a smaller dataset first. I have been using just 10rows and 30M cols that I can load easily but it fails on doing any operations on it( the error says it cannot build an index over it). For computing on the whole matrix I am sure it will take a hell lot of time. I want to be sure that the algorithm will work and not give me up error after running 2 or 3 days. :)

Comment: what generated this huge data file? is it possible to generate it in a different format? do you have control over the generation of the file?

Comment: @Shai : As I mentioned in previous comments this data is generated for  nlp and I can't regenerate the entire data again(due to time and system constraint). I just want to do some matrix operations on this matrix.

Comment: so, if you can cast your toy example to `sparse` and work with it, you'll have to implement the read method to read directly into a sparse representation.

Comment: You have to block import your matrix, cast each imported block to sparse and store it into a cell array. Once you imported all blocks, just concatenate them all at once. You will notice that 180GB will vanish if your sparsity is 99%.]

Comment: @OlegKomarov note that even if the matrix is very very small in size, the total number of elements will still be limited. The maximum index number will be limited by his own system, 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: See [this discussion](http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Re-Pkg-octave-devel-Bug-706376-octave-sparse-matrix-n-2-16-td4652439.html) about the size limit of a matrix in Octave (sparse matrix inclusive). Basically boils down to the fact that Octave uses a 32bit integer internally to index the matrix. You can build Octave with [64 bit indexing](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Compiling-Octave-with-64_002dbit-Indexing.html) but all of Octave dependencies will also need it.

Comment: MATLAB allows indices in sparse to be `2^48-1 = 281474976710655` where `3e4 * 3e6` is smaller (for 64 bit OS)

Answer (score 1):

if there are few enough nonzero entries, I suggest creating a sparse matrix S with appropriate dimensions and max nonzero entries; see [matlab create sparse matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html).  Then as @oleg komarov described, load the matrix in blocks and assign the nonzero entries from each block into the correct address in the sparse matrix S.  I feel that if your matrix is sparse enough, then loading it is really the only difficulty you face.  I had similar issues with large transfer operators.

Comment: This is indeed an option if matrix is sparse, and you can also try to cast it as logical() and use as many logical operators as possible (which preserve the logical type), but then if your matrix is really huge you will still run into memory overflow or 32 bits indices overflow (because the max number of indices is also limited, even if sparse!).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered performing your processing in blocks? Transposition and multiplications work very well with block matrix processing (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix) and that will get you around any limitations about the indices.

This wouldn't help you with matrix inversion though unless you can decompose your matrix in blocks when blocks that aren't on the diagonal are completely empty, which isn't stated in your assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Octave has a limit in both the memory resources of about 2GB and the maximum number of indices a matrix can hold of about 2^32 (for 32 bits Octave). MatLab doesn't have such a memory limit, since it will use all of your memory resources, swapping file included. Thus you could try with MatLab by setting a huge swapfile, you may then compute your operations (but it will anyway take quite along time...).

If you are interested by other approaches, you may take a look into out-of-core computing which aims to promote new methods to process huge datasets that cannot reside all in memory, but rather store it on disk and load efficiently the bits that are necessary.

For a practical approach, you may take a look into Blaze for Python (notice: still in development!).